# Ошибка при передаче элементов структуры в функцию fgets

Tags: c, файлы, struct

Программа компилируется нормально, но при исполнении завершается аварийно. Проблема где-то в цикле, кажется, при обращении к элементам структуры.
Файл записан исправно и читается, а ошибка - стандартное прекращение работы программы.

[image: Привожу файл]
[image: Вот что значит стандартное прекращение работы]

Структура

```
typedef struct university_notes {//LAB2 == 80
  char fac[LAB2][LAB2];
  char spec[LAB2][LAB2];
  int am;
} unotes;
```

Функция с ошибкой

```
void read_data(unotes *un) {
  FILE* f;
  un->am = -1;
  if((f = fopen("2ndfac.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error reading 1st file");
    return;
  }
  while(!feof(f)) {
    un->am++;
    fgets(un->fac[un->am], LAB2, f);
  }
}
```

Comment: гм... в цикле проблем не вижу... если точно как-то удостоверился, что проблема в нём,  то я бы подозревал, что память под структуру не [правильно] выделена... как в win более адекватное представление об ошибке получить — не подскажу, но я бы начал копать для начала в эту сторону...

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком и всё увидите своими глазами.

Comment: А как вызывается указанная функция read_data - может там память под структуру не выделяется или выделяется неправильно.

Comment: Все решено KoVadim был прав, спасибо PinkTux, отладчик все показал.